# How to use react/tanstack query useMutation in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm currently converting the logic in my mern (with typescript) project to use React/Tanstack query to learn this tool better.

I want to use useMutation to handle the post request logic from the details inputted in the form, in this login component but can't figure out how to do this. Any tips would be appreciated thanks. Below is the code from my login component

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");

  const [state, setState] = useContext(UserContext);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let response;
    const { data: loginData } = await axios.post("http://localhost:5001/auth/login", {
      email,
      password,
    });
    response = loginData;

    if (response.errors.length) {
      return setErrorMsg(response.errors[0].msg);
    }

    setState({
      data: {
        id: response.data.user.id,
        email: response.data.user.email,
        stripeCustomerId: response.data.user.stripeCustomerId,
      },
      loading: false,
      error: null,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token); 
    axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`;

    navigate("/dashboard");
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-card">
      <div>
        <h3>Login</h3>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="login-card-mb">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        </div>

        <div className="login-card-mb">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        {errorMsg && <p>{errorMsg}</p>}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting up your project to use React Query ( Check the docs if you have not). You want to extract your api call to a separate function that takes an object. This object will hold the values you would like to post.

```
const Login = (dataToPost) => {
  let res = await axios.post('url', dataToPost)
  return res.data
}
```

Now that you have that, you can import `useMutation` from React Query. Once imported you can now use the hook. UseQuery, useMutation both contain a data variable so no need to create state for the data returned from your endpoint. In this example, I'm deconstructing the data and loading state. But most importantly the mutate function. Which allows you to fire off your api call. We add our api call to the hook. I'm renaming the mutate function to `doLogin`. It's a habit

```
const {data,isLoading,mutate:doLogin} = useMutation(Login)
```

Finally we can just call `mutate(objectWithValues)` wherever you want in your code. The `data` will initially be null and `isLoading` will be true once called. To tie it all together. Your handleSubmit could look as follows

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  doLogin({email,password})
}
```

You also have the option of running functions on a success or error of the mutation

```
const {data,isLoading,mutate: doLogin} = 
useMutation(Login, {
  onError: (err) => console.log("The error",err),
  onSuccess:(someStuff)=>console.log("The data being returned",someStuff)
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort into explaining this! I've managed to get where i want now with the info provided